# ¿Como hacer para que highchart muestre la fecha en las categorias?

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

El siguiente código es parte de un js de highcharts, por lo cual solo publicaré lo que creo es necesario y debería ser parte del error:

```
    xAxis: {
        categories: [{
                     data: (function() {
                         var data = [];
                    <?php
                        for($i = 0 ;$i<count($rawdata);$i++){
                    ?>
                    data.push(['<?php echo $rawdata[$i]["fecha"];?>']);
                    <?php } ?>
                return data;
                     })()   
    }],
        type: 'datetime'
        },

    series: [{
        name: 'Temperature',
                     data: (function() {
                         var data = [];
                    <?php
                        for($i = 0 ;$i<count($rawdata);$i++){
                    ?>
                    data.push([<?php echo $rawdata[$i]["valor"];?>]);
                    <?php } ?>
                return data;
                     })()   
    }],

});
console.timeEnd('line');

        </script>
</html>
```

El código extrae los campos "fecha" y "valor" desde una base de datos mysql local.

El problema es que al graficar las fechas no se muestran como debería, apareciendo de la siguiente forma:

[image: Problema Highcharts]

Siendo que en realidad está extrayendo los datos bien. A continuación el código fuente del resultado:

```
    xAxis: {
        categories: [{
                     data: (function() {
                         var data = [];
                                        data.push(['2020-02-13 00:00:00']);
                                        data.push(['2020-02-12 08:18:23']);
                                    return data;
                     })()   
    }],
        type: 'datetime'
        },

    series: [{
        name: 'Temperature',
                     data: (function() {
                         var data = [];
                                        data.push([4]);
                                        data.push([5]);
                                    return data;
                     })()   
    }],

});
```

¿Que puede estar pasando?

Comment: ¿Los valores en `data` van como arrays dentro de otro array? ¿Si pruebas así qué pasa: `data.push('2020-02-13 00:00:00'); data.push('2020-02-12 08:18:23');`

Comment: Lo descubrí. Era que, para poder mostrar las fechas como categorías, debían ser mostradas así:

xAxis: {
        categories: ['2020-02-13 00:00:00','2020-02-12 08:18:23'];

Ya que es la forma en que highcharts las reconoce. Así que modifiqué el código para que quedara así y funcionó.

¡De todas maneras muchas gracias!